# Searching Lotus Notes Databases

Tags: search, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I have around 50 lotus notes databases which I need to search through (including RTFs and attachments) based on a rather complicated query (for example: If customer = a or b or c or d or e ... or z & product = x or y) then == match; and a tag to (e.g. tag = found or not found)

However, I wasn't sure the best way to go about this and wanted to check three options.

1. Using Lotus' 'Search in View' should, after indexing, search all the databases - however I am unsure if it will accept a long, complicated search query
2. Coding an agent in Lotus SCRIPT to basically perform the search in 1. but this might be a way of getting it to accept a complicated query
3. Using external software (e.g. X1 Professional Search) to search outside of Lotus Notes (however I am not sure if I will be able to tag the files if I identify them in windows explorer).

Edit: My idea is:

```
Sub Initialise
Dim session as New NotesSession
Dim db as NotesDatabase
Dim dc as NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Dim searcy_query$

'On current database
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
'Force index of database
Call db.UpdateFTIndex(True)

'Construct QUERY
search_query = "(Customer1|Customer2) & (Product1|Product2)"
'Search
Set dc = db.FTSearch(query, 0)

If dc.Count=0 Then
                Msgbox "No matches!"
                Exit Sub
End If

‘Tag the matched documents with “Flag”
Call dc.StampAll("Flag","Active)")
End Sub
```

However, I am not sure if this will return all matches and also regarding @TRIM and @UPPER (where to put them into the query as I will be searching all fields and RTFs rather than specific ones)

Comment: For all the DB, is it always the same search ? if yes use a view with the complexe select formula.
Do you need exact result or approx ? If exactitude is important, I do not recommand FT index
what about creating a view in all db that will be use in lotuscript ?
What is the size of each DB?

Comment: Hi @Emmanuel Gleizer, many thanks for your reply. It will always be the same search however I will not be searching the same fields, for example I always want to search for Cust1 or Cust 3 and Product 1 but these may be in different fields of the database or even attachments (and have no fields at all), etc. I would need exact results - all files in the database that contain (anywhere) mentions of Cust1, etc.  I have updated my original post with a sample of code that I had on mind. Thanks very much for your help again!

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Searching more than one database at a time can of course be done "manually" by searching each individual database, collection the results and find a way to present the documents "somehow" (what will not be easy, as documents from different databases cannot be shown in "one" view - you would need to use "shadow- documents" or a web- approach (e.g. XPages))

BUT: Lotus Notes has a built-in function to do this, it is called "Domain Indexer". You can read more about how to setup "domain index" [in this IBM Link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21280065) or in your administration help.

Examples for using the domain- index for multi- database- searches can be found in catalog.nsf in the form "DomainQuery".

The search- string does not have a limit as far as I know, so that you can do very complex searches with this technique and it gives you all the matches.

If you search for a LotusScript- Solution, check the documentation for NotesDatabase.ftdomainsearch for example code like this (taken from developer help):

> The following code, when placed in a button on a search form within a directory catalog database, searches the directory for the specified query string, and returns all results.

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim w As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim doc as NotesDocument
    Dim quer As String
    Dim srdoc as NotesDocument


    Set db=s.CurrentDatabase
    Set uidoc = w.currentdocument
    uidoc.refresh
    Set doc=uidoc.Document

    quer=doc.query(0)

    On Error Resume Next     
    If db.isopen Then
        If Err <> 0 Then
            Messagebox STR_DBOPEN_ERROR, 0 , STR_ERROR
            Err = 0
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Set srdoc = db.ftdomainsearch(quer, 0)

        If Err <> 0 Then
            Messagebox STR_NDF , 0 , STR_LOTUS_NOTES
            Err=0
            Exit Sub
        End If

        srdoc.Form="SearchResults"
        Call w.EditDocument(False, srdoc, True)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you also intend to search Rich Text, the simplier way is Full Text Search, you got the point!

The syntax for your query is:

```
generic_text or ([_CreationDate]<07.10.2014 and ([CustomerFieldName]="Smith" or [CustomerFieldName]="Wesson"))
```

For formating the Result, I'ld suggest looking at:[AppendDocLink](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_APPENDDOCLINK_METHOD.html) for something like:

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As New NotesDatabase("", "resu.nsf")
Dim newDoc As NotesDocument
Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument

Set newDoc = New NotesDocument( db )
Set rtitem = New NotesRichTextItem( newDoc, "Body" )
'you have to loop on your 50 DBs
'Search =>from your code
Set dc = db.FTSearch(query, 0)
while not doc is nothing 
     Call rtitem.AppendDocLink( doc, db.Title )
     Call rtitem.AddTab( 1 )
     Call rtitem.AppendText( doc.FieldImportantInResult( 0 ) )
     Call rtitem.AddNewLine( 1 )
     Set doc = dc.GetNextDocument( doc )
Wend
newDoc.save true, true
'this part is not to add it you plane to run your search in background
Dim w As New NotesUIWorkspace
Call w.EditDocument(False, newDoc, True)
```